# Создание прозрачного фона в GD

Tags: gd, php, png

Уже задавал этот вопрос на cyberforum, но ничего внятного не получил, может быть тут помогут. Проблема в создании прозрачного фона для изображений (пробовал только в png). При копировании изображения (созданного функцией imagecreatefrompng) для изменения размеров (функцией imagecopyresempled) на новое изображение (созданное функцией imagecreatetruecolor) появляется черный фон.

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('1.png'); //исходное изображение с прозрачностью
$result = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); //создаем новое изображение для копирования в него исходного       
imagecopyresampled($result, $img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $src_w, $src_h);
$img = $result; //теперь просвечивается черный фон
```

выход вроде как бы есть

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('1.png'); //исходное изображение с прозрачностью
$result = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); //создаем новое изображение для копирования в него исходного
$black = ImageColorAllocate($result, 0, 0, 0); // черный цвет
$trans = imagecolortransparent($result, $black); // теперь черный прозрачен
ImageFill($result, 0, 0, $black); //заливка прозрачным цветом
//изображение теперь прозрачное - проверял
imagecopyresampled($result, $img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $src_w, $src_h);
$img = $result; //теперь нет черного цвета
```

черный цвет во всем изображении исчез. хотя в мануале написано, что только для ранее наклееных изображений это работает. или я не так понял.

> Замечание: 
> Прозрачный цвет является свойством изображения, прозрачность не является свойством цвета. Если вы задали цвет как прозрачный, некоторые области изображения этого цвета нарисованные ранее станут прозрачными.

если черный цвет сменить на белый, белый тоже стирается и остаются непонятные разводы. что я могу делать не так, либо в чем моя ошибка? если кто знает другой способ, прошу подсказать. GD конфиг:

```
GD Support  |   enabled
GD Version  |   2.0
PNG Support |   enabled
libPNG Version  |   1.2.46
```

Comment: Посмотрите imagesavealpha (и отключение imagealphablending)

Comment: спасибо, imagesavealpha в true помгло исправить проблему. правда не понятно, как это влияет. и imagealphablending должно быть в false, иначе фон будет черным

Comment: @Heleg Так указывает сохранять ли альфа-канал (прозрачность) или нет.

Что касается imagealphablending. Перевод на русский мне кажется несколько неуклюжим -- в оригинале есть такое предложение: The resulting pixel is opaque -- "результирующий пиксел непрозрачен", т.е. после сопряжения прозрачность теряется. Из http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php:

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor( $w, $h );
    imagealphablending( $im, false );
    $col = imagecolorallocate( $im, 0, 0, 0, 127 );
    imagefilledrectangle( $im, 0, 0, $w, $h, $col );
    imagealphablending( $im, true );