# Задать прозрачность фона у PNG в php

Tags: php

Когда загружаю png, то фон становится чёрным, подскажите где нужно дописать, чтобы фон оставался прозрачным.

```
<?php

class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $compression=75,$image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $permissions=null) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

[Создание прозрачного фона в GD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/172719/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-gd)